# Python: Encode base64 string to put it on headers

Tags: python, base64

I'm using this code for encode user_name and password and put it to headers.

```
def login_as_user(self,user):
    encode_login = base64.b64encode(bytes(str(user['email'] + ":" +user['password']),'utf8'))
    headers = { Config.API_AUTHORIZATION:"Basic "+str(encode_login)}
    response = requests.requestd("POST", self.url_path , data="", headers=headers)
    return response
```

With the

> user_name = test@test.com and password = 1.

When I converted encode_login to str , the output always *b'dGVzdEB0ZXN0LmNvbTox'* , then when convert to string, it include b'. This makes my headers when requesting is wrong.

Please help, how can I solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply decode your data to `UTF8` by using `decode()`.

For example, if your variable is:

```
a = b'dGVzdEB0ZXN0LmNvbTox'
# Or:
# a = a.decode('UTF8') 
a = a.decode()
print(a)
```

Output:

```
>> 'dGVzdEB0ZXN0LmNvbTox'
```

Otherwise, this will print:

```
base64.b64encode(bytes("hello", 'utf8')).decode()
>>> 'aGVsbG8='
```

So, in your question, you have just to modify this line:

```
headers = { Config.API_AUTHORIZATION:"Basic " + str(encode_login)}
```

By:

```
headers = { Config.API_AUTHORIZATION:"Basic " + encode_login.decode()}
```

Comment: Thanks Chiheb, but encode_login is a bytes, not a str, then it doest not have func like encode() .

Comment: @kennytm Thanks! it was a typo error late at this night.

Comment: @scorpion i've updated my answer. You can use `decode()` and it will solve your issue.